# Serialize/deserialize instance/instances with XML

Tags: c#, xml, serialization, instances

I'm learning C# and the best way to learn is practice and practice, well I'm making this little program where I have the class "brand" and I have a little menu where I can add brands, modify or remove them, then another little menu where I have the option to add sales, or add stock etc...
The problem comes when I want to save or load the data... I can't find a good way to save an instance E.G. (Menu -> add brand. reopen app Menu -> add stock )
I have tried a lot of tutorials, xml and binary serialization etc... but can't work this out. Can you please help me to find a good way to instantiate a brand class, save it, and later open, see or modify it?

Here is a pastebin, I know there are a lot of issues etc... but my main problem is the data saving/loading. 
[Pastebin](http://pastebin.com/ttfgsJnG/%22pastebin%22)

Thanks a lot,
Erwin.

Comment: please show what have you tried, you need to post here code samples

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please read [ask]. Key phrases: "Search, and research" and "Explain ... any difficulties that have prevented you from solving it yourself".

Comment: Hello, and thanks. But I've already searched a lot and read tutorials, and I've already specified that the main issue was with the data saving/loading.

Comment: Line 185, I think just replace 'this' with brands & use AddRange (Also probably the same for Line 190)

Answer (score 0):

Working example can be found [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/fMAREa)

Fix for your code can be found [here](http://pastebin.com/nP7AzyLw)
(BTW: you are forcing logic in constructor and that is not good!)